# Textview nullpointerexception in android

Tags: android

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home_screen.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("first-name", firstname);
                startActivity(i);
```

Second Activity

```
TextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b!=null)
    {

        String d = b.getString("first-name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), d,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I have edited the code..
Getting NullPointerException on Textview or even on EditText of second activity and firstname is the string not a textview. Even Toast is printing wat i want on the second activity screen so the data is getting passed.. Thanks for the replies guys though stil hunting for answer..

Comment: Hi firstname Is String name or textview name?

Comment: post the relevant code please.. This is not helpful.

Comment: if firstname is a TextView, you should use method getText() at least.

Comment: Post your full class code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the code

`setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);`

before your `findViewById` ??

You must have to set layouts view before assign any object from that layout file.

Comment: I AM SO SORRY...this is silly mistake as i am a beginner...THanks vipul bhai...thanks al...

Answer (score 0):

If `firstname` is your textview name:

```
String FName;
FName = firstname.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home_screen.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("first-name", FName);
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. My guess would be the `firstname` variable is `null` or not a string in the first activity. That's why it's `null` in second one.

Comment: Getting NullPointerException on Textview of second activity. So your guess might me wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok but I can't understand why it is not working. May be you made some mistakes in your code. If possible show us the full code. 
I can describe some solution for your problem. 
You said you Getting `NullPointerException` on Textview of second activity. In your second activity you did not declare the TextView. Where is your TextView in second activity? At first try to log the text value in second activity like this `Log.d("TAG",""+d);` If it return value then the problem is in your TextView. Please at first check your first and second activity again. Hope you will able to find your problem or you can post your whole code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home_screen.class); i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 if(firstname!=null){
 i.putExtra("first-name", firstname);
 startActivity(i);
 }else{ Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "firstname is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```